# Getting unexpected result with jquery ajax post method from php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my form from which i am expecting post results in my div id="response"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX POST</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="submit"]').click(function(){
            var username=$('input[name="username"]').attr("value");
            var password=$('input[name="password"]').attr("value");
            var data1=encodeURIComponent(username);
            var data2=encodeURIComponent(password);
            $.post("response.php",{username:data1,password:data2},function(data){
            $("#form").hide();
            $("#response").text(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
<form action="response.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br/>
<input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br/>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="response"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my server side script

```
<?php
echo $_POST["username"]."<br/>";
echo $_POST["password"];
?>
```

After filling the form and clicking the submit button the response that i get is `"<br/>"`
I don't understand this.Please explain.

Comment: `.attr("value")` gets/sets the default value of the input, not the current value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the input value you need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) not [.attr('value')](http://api.jquery.com/attr). `.attr('value')` will return the value of the attribute which is `''`(empty string) here

```
var username=$('input[name="username"]').val();
var password=$('input[name="password"]').val();
```

Comment: still why is tit that i get "<br/>" in my result instead of line break in response?

Comment: because you have used [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)